# Coredata Update Entity last item Type ' Type' has no subscript members error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have Settings `Entity` in `CoreData` when I try to update entity last

> Type ' Settings.Type' has no subscript members error

How can I fix it ? 
How can I update last row  Values, from Settings Entity

**My Settings Entity**
Attributes;

```
id.  = Integer32
name = String
age = String
```

My codes under below.

```
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                        Settings[0].id = json["id"]["namesettings"].int32Value
 Settings[0].name = json["name"]["name"].stringValue
 Settings[0].age = json["age"]["age"].stringValue
                        appDelegate.saveContext()
```

**Settings[0]**  line gives this error.

Thank you !

Comment: You need to show us the declaration of Settings

Comment: how you imagine using entity as an array?

Comment: @NiravD I added My Settings Entity , Attributes in my question. only have thats

Comment: Is `Settings` a type or an instance? According to the error it seems to be the type. That cannot work.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Are you want to create new entry in coredata?

Comment: @NiravD no I want to update only last row

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper What do you mean by last row here, last object of array?

Comment: @NiravD yeah last object of My Settings Entity

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper For that you need to first fetch that object from the entity

Comment: @NiravD how can I update ? how can I do it can you write example code for me

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper You have asked for example, but not respond after it, is it works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know this is exactly you want but for updating the `CoreData` `Entity` you need to have `NSMangedObject` and for that you need to first fetch the records from `CoreData`.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Settings> = Settings.fetchRequest()
let settings = try! context.fetch(request)

//Now access the last object from it edit it
if let obj = settings.last {
    obj.id = json["id"]["namesettings"].int32Value
    obj.name = json["name"].stringValue
    obj.age = json["age"].stringValue
    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```